# Надо ли по данному тексту, заверять нотариально, трудовые книжки?

Tags: общие-вопросы

4) документы, подтверждающие наличие у потенциальных поставщиков квалифицированных специалистов, имеющих опыт работы в области, соответствующей предмету закупок не менее 3 месяцев (подтвержденный наличием нотариально засвидетельствованных копии документов установленного образца, о прохождении специальной подготовки охранника (специального курса обучения охранника) и копиями трудовых книжек на каждого привлекаемого работника);

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, не нужно, нотариально заверяются копии свидетельств о присвоении квалификации, сертификатов, дипломов , а копии трудовых книжек обычно заверяются в самом учреждении. Судя по содержанию фразы,нотариально засвидетельствованы должны быть только " копии документов установленного образца о прохождении специальной подготовки охранника"

Answer (score 1):

"По этому тексту" можно думать о чем угодно. О запятой, например, после слова "образца". Или о том, почему однородными членами являются "наличием" и "копиями".

Но если не по этому документу, а по сложившейся практике, то копии трудовых книжек спокон веку заверяются в отделе кадров, а не у нотариуса. Так что скорее всего и тут не имеется ввиду иное.